# Error en cargue de sitio web alojado en Hosting Gratuito

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli, hosting

Cordial saludo, espero se encuentren bien, les escribe Hernán Martínez desde Colombia, necesito preguntarles por favor acerca del inconveniente que se me ha presentado en cuanto a un pequeño sitio que tengo desarrollado haciendo uso de las siguientes Lenguajes:
Php, Js, Css, Html y una pequeña Base de datos en Mysql.

Tengo alojado el pequeño sitio web en el servidor gratuito Infinityfree, la ultima vez que funciono bien la aplicación fue el pasado 28 de marzo y ahora voy a visitar el Sitio y me muestra el siguiente error:

Este sitio web no puede proporcionar una conexión segura
misitioweb.com ha enviado una respuesta no válida.
•   Prueba a ejecutar Diagnósticos de red de Windows.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Buscando por internet me dicen que debo tanto desocupar la cache del navegador, así como deshabilitar algunos atributos del antivirus, pero en todos los dispositivos que he probado el sitio web me muestra el mismo error.

Agradezco me puedan indicar que podrá estar sucediendo, si es problema del servidor en donde está alojado el sitio, o por que otra situación se me está presentando el inconveniente.

Muchas gracias!.

Comment: Te ha caducado tu certificado SSL seguramente, o quizás nunca tuvistes ninguno. Prueba de acceder a ella sin la S, es decir, en lugar de `https://misitioweb.com` prueba con `http://misitioweb.com`.

Comment: Muchas gracias maestrogurú, lo que me dijiste era el inconveniente un abrazo, saludos!